# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

after updating some outdates addons, i got this error on my site, and its not running...

```
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.value) = '0') AND (start_time <= '2017-03-12') AND (end_time >= '2017-03-' at line 2, query was: SELECT main_table.* FROM bannerslider_banner AS main_table LEFT JOIN bannerslider_value AS status ON main_table.banner_id = status.banner_id AND status.store_id = 1 AND status.attribute_code = 'status' WHERE (bannerslider_id = '1') AND (IF(status.value IS NULL, main_table.status, status.value) = '0') AND (start_time <= '2017-03-12') AND (end_time >= '2017-03-12') ORDER BY order_banner ASC
```

any hints?

Comment: Check if `value` column exists in `bannerslider_value` and `bannerslider_banner` Mysql tables.